# Is it possible to deploy Amazon elasticsearch cluster with certain version of elasticsearch engine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

So, question is in title.
By default it deploys 1.5.2 version.
Is it possible to downgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not, Amazon Elastic Search is a managed service, in exchange for them taking on the responsibility of managing everything for you, you give up some control. Picking the version you want to run is one of those things.

You can of course spin up your own EC2 instances and install whatever version you would like to run instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I read in faq: `aws currently supports Elasticsearch 1.5.2.`